# Getting table header cell contents

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I have the following html:

```
<div>
    <table class="month">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th class="month">February 2017</th>
            </tr>
        ...
```

I am trying to get "February 2017" with jquery so i can send it with ajax to a view. I've tried a few things and can't get this to work. This is what I've got at the moment:

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: my_url,
        method: 'GET', 
        data: {
            current: $('#month').find("th.month").html(), // data you need to pass to your function
            other: "other"
        },
        success : function (json) {
            console.log(json);        
        }
    });
});
```

It triggers when I click a link with a next id. The other data is sending just fine. current returns None. I've tried using val() too.

The convention of getting divs / table / th etc really confuses me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The # operator finds based on ID, not class (which is .).

From your html, all you need to do to find "February 2017" is to use:

```
$("th.month").html()
```

JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/fy3bdyLb/

Comment: That's solved it thanks. It's useful to know . is for classes I didn't know the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<th class="month" id="month">February 2017</th>
```

You called "#month" in your ajax but you have "month" as class in your TH. It should be ".month" in your ajax data.

"#" for ID

"." for class

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting `<table class="month">` with `$('#month')`, it should be `$('.month')` as it is a class and not an id.
I'm not sure it's the only problem though.